# How to move image a little bit down without affecting the input box in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="xd"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/80" alt="facebook logo" /></li>
      <li class="hey">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search Facebook" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I've tried to padding-top the image, but it moves the input along with image like one block. How can I fix that i.e. separate the image and move it to where I want?

Comment: You could play with `position` property (absolute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```css
img {
  transform: translateY(10%);
}
```

Change the percentage value around until you get it right. It can also take negative values. I don't know the rest of your code, so I can't tell if this would be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform to move the image without effecting other elements. But if you're trying to vertically align the 2 elements use flex or grid as suggested by Julio

```
img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translateY(30px)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this

transform: translateY(X%);

X value this is the percentage value you get.